# C# lambda filter by condition in sublist

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I filter a List based on condition in a sublist. I have a supplier with Contacts, I want to filter by FirstName of the Contact. Below is a traditional foreach, if filtering. Does it possible to do similar with lambda expression ?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ContactFirstName))
{
    List<CorporationSupplier> temp = new List<CorporationSupplier>();
    foreach (CorporationSupplier corporationSupplier in filteredCorporationSuppliers)
    {
        var contacts = corporationSupplier.Supplier.SupplierContacts;
        foreach (SupplierContact supplierContact in contacts)
        {
            if (supplierContact?.Person?.FirstName.ToLower() == model.ContactFirstName)
            {
                temp.Add(corporationSupplier);
            }
        }
    }
    filteredCorporationSuppliers = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) on the sub list. For example:

```
filteredCorporationSuppliers.Where(s => 
    s.Supplier.SupplierContacts.Any(c => 
        c.Person?.FirstName.ToLower() == model.ContactFirstName));
```